# Update static resources for iPad (iOS) application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, auto-update

I'm working on simple iPad applications which contains only one webView with static HTML code (something like presentation). From time to time the HTML code is changing (add new slides, remove other).

The Apps must be able to work offline!
I'm using Xcode 9 with Swift 4, and I'm still a newbie with this.

What is the simple solution to update this HTML resources and store on the user device (when the device has the internet connection, of course)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your HTML resources to app's Document Directory for load or update it

When user run app, you can check your resources existed in Document Directory or not.

- If not, you simple copy it from your app bundle to Document Directory.
- If existed, just load HTML file from Document Directory